# MongoDB compound index for query

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query, compound-index

I am new to MongoDB indexing and was wondering if it makes sense to create an index for the following query.

```
{
        $and: [
            {_id: {$ne: "SOME_ID"}},
            {_id: {$nin: ["ID1","ID2","ID3"]}},
            {_id: {$nin: ["ID4","ID5","ID6"]}}
        ],
        age: {$gte: 18, $lte: 50},
        gender: "male",
        location: {
            $nearSphere: {
                $geometry: {
                    type: "Point",
                    coordinates: ["some_valid_longitude", "some_valid_latitude"]
                },
                $maxDistance: 1000
            }
        },
        work: "work",
        registrationComplete: true
}
```

Is an index for the above query needed? and how to create it?
Will the index affect write speed?

Comment: Why the unnecessary duplication, `$and: [
            {_id: {$ne: "SOME_ID"}},
            {_id: {$nin: ["ID1","ID2","ID3"]}},
            {_id: {$nin: ["ID4","ID5","ID6"]}}
        ],` can simply be `_id: {$nin: ["SOME_ID", "ID1","ID2","ID3","ID4","ID5","ID6"] }` ?

Comment: @chridam good point, I guess that's the initial optimisation I can start with.
How about the index?

Comment: That depends on several factors like how often you run the query,  the kinds of queries you expect, the ratio of reads to writes, the amount of free memory on your system etc since indexes come with a write performance cost, but are more than worth the cost for frequent queries on large data set. Consider the relative frequency of each query in the application and whether the query justifies an index.

Comment: @chridam the above query is expected to have more reads than writes, so I am assuming this a good use case for an index.
do u think the following is a correct index:
{_id: 1, age: 1, gender: 1, location: 1, work: 1, registrationComplete: 1}

location is already indexed as 2d_sphere

Comment: I believe that index will result in greatly increased query performance as it contains all the fields scanned by the query. Read more about it here [Indexing Strategies](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/applications/indexes/#indexing-strategies).